# How to batch convert JPEG images with jpegtran on Windows

Tags: windows, batch, jpeg, jpegtran

Is it possible to batch convert a folder of JPEG images using jpegtran on Windows?
I normally use the following command for one file, but I'm not sure how to apply it to an entire directory of JPEG files:

```
jpegtran -copy none -optimize a.jpg b.jpg
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### How do I operate `jpegtran` on a bunch of images at once?

I've not used `jpegtran` myself before, but based on your example command you can enter the following at a command prompt:

```
cd /path/to/where/images/are/stored
for %f in (*.jpg) do jpegtran -copy none -optimize %f %~nf-new.jpg
```

Note that **this assumes you are running from `cmd.exe` command prompt**; if you are in a batch file the `%`s need doubled to `%%`.

See the [`for` reference for more information](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/for.mspx).

### Explanation

`for %f in (*.jpg)` - loop through all files ending in .jpg extension using the variable `%f`

`do jpegtran -copy none -optimize` - `do` this action (using your example `jpegtran` above)

`%f` - variable with filename plus extension (*original file*)

`%~nf` - variable with filename **without extension** as per [reference above](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/for.mspx) (*new file with `-new.jpg` appended*)

Comment: I never knew about that `for` command from the Windows command line. Very awesome. It should be noted that `jpegtran.exe` either needs to be in the images folder you're running the command from, or it has to be registered as part of the `PATH` environment variable. Also, neither of your links worked, but I found information about `for` [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx).